# Setting Protonmail on default email mobile phone app

Tags: applications, email

On my android samsung edge s6 I added a new protonmail account. The phone alerts me saying the server doesn't answer.

Here the configuration I tried:

```
IMAP server: 127.0.0.1,TLS,port: 143
SMTP server: 127.0.0.1,TLS,port: 587
--------------------------------------------
IMAP server: 127.0.0.1,SSL,port: 993
SMTP server: 127.0.0.1,SSL,port: 465
--------------------------------------------
IMAP server: 127.0.0.1,SSL,port: 1143
SMTP server: 127.0.0.1,SSL,port: 1025
```

I has been always alerted that "it is not possible to connect with the server".

The app email manager is the samsung's default one.

Comment: The server address can not be correct. 127.0.0.1 is always your device, hence the Protonmail server would have to be located on your Android phone - which is not the case unless there is a ProtonMail app that redirects the data to the real server. Hence it looks like you understood something wrong how to set-up a Protonmail account.

Comment: I was confident about 127.0.0.1 because I saw https://stackoverflow.com/a/56554287. I was wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protonmail does not work on Android in third party Mail applications (because the ProtonMail Bridge application is not available for Android). You have to use the web interface or the [ProtonMail app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.protonmail.android).

Cite from the ProtonMail help pages:

> At this time Protonmail does not integrate with third party email clients (IMAP/SMTP) on Android due to the technology ProtonMail utilizes within web browsers to encrypt and decrypt your messages. [[source]](https://protonmail.com/support/knowledge-base/android/)

Answer (score 0):

One convoluted solution would be to have a Linux-based server running Proton Mail Bridge that is available to the phone on the Cloud or through VPN (say available at home if using a robust firewall like OpenVPN).

If more details are required, please ask.